# How can I get ReSharper to correctly find an MVC3 section in an alternate layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout, resharper, partial-views

R# is incorrectly reporting one of my MVC3 views as having an error. I have 2 layouts, each with different sections defined:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/layout2.cshtml";
}
@section Layout2Section { @* Layout2Section is red, reported as error by R#. *@
    <span>Injected into LayoutSection2</span>
}
```

The view displays fine in a browser. Here is code from layout2:

```
@RenderSection("Layout2Section", false)
@if (!IsSectionDefined("Layout2Section"))
{
    <span>default layout2 section</span>
}
```

There is another layout view in `~/Views/Shared` named `_Layout.cshtml`, the default in an MVC3 project. R# is only giving intellisense for sections in `_Layout.cshtml`, not `layout2.cshtml`. I have tried prefixing with an underscore, it does not work. If I try to define any section in `layout2.cshtml` that is not defined in `_Layout.cshtml`, R# is calling it an error. How to disable this, either to tell R# that the view is a section definer, or to get rid of the "1 file with errors" message?

**Update**

After derigel's comment, I realized that the above code is not exactly what I have in my project. Specifically, the line that defines the layout uses T4MVC like so:

```
@{
    Layout = MVC.Shared.Views.layout;
}
```

If I change it to a string as in the original question, the R# error goes away. @Derigel, shall I still create a test project and post to your tracker? I just reproduced the above update in a brand new MVC3 project, after adding the T4MVC lib.

Comment: Is it worth the trouble?

Comment: @RobertHarvey absolutely. Considering many views could use this section, and R# would report each of them as a file with error.

Comment: @olivehour, I can't repeat your problem. Can you create issue in [our tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP) and attach demo project.

Comment: @derigel see the question update. R# reports as an error when the Layout refers to a variable, instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@olivehour Oh, now I get it. It's known limitation of R# - it can detect layouts only in constant string literals. Can you change T4 templates to generate constants instead of readonly fields?

Comment: I might be able to do that, but I don't want to. It is much easier to just use a string, or have a separate constant variable for the 2 layouts. Thanks for the answer.